# how to reverse slice python list

Tags: python

Would appreciate some help, how do you slice a python list like example below:

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

I want the slice in a loop so output would be:

8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 
8,7,6,5,4,3,2 
8,7,6,5,4,3 
8,7,6,5,4 
8,7,6,5 
8,7,6 
8,7 
8

should be in function like :

```
    for i in range(len(a)):
        print(a["slice here"])
```

i've tried [-1::-1-i] not sure anymore? thought this would be straightforward ?

Comment: `[a[:i:-1] for i in range(-len(a) - 1, -1)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i:len(a)][::-1])
```

OR

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if i==0:    
        print(a[-1:i:-1]+[a[0]]) 
    else:   
        print(a[-1:i-1:-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do it like this friendo, in this case I reverse the list, than I do a reverse range so you can print it out. According to the given index

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8][::-1]

for i in range(len(l),0,-1):
   print(l[:i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `:i-len(a)-1:-1` for your `"slice here"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reverse the list and then remove the last number in the list.

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a.reverse()
for i in range( 1, len(a)):
    print(a[:-i])
```

if you want without the brackets

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a.reverse()
for i in range( 1, len(a)):
    print(str(a[:-i])[1:-1])
```

Comment: This is different from the expected output of OP.